# AngularJS + BootstrapUI : Autocomplete is not loading options

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

Im trying to load common names using Ui-Bootstrap Autocomplete.

When I type, I can see the List is being loaded EXACTLY the number of times that letter repeats! But its not showing the names. I can see the href tags has no value!

Im definitely missing something here. Thoughts?

Pen : https://codepen.io/vbbalaji/pen/qBRjRGm

```
        <span class='py-2 mb-2'>Please enter your name</span>
        <div class='container mb-2'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-3 text-right py-2 my-1'>Name</div>
                <div class='col-9 vlight-blue py-2 my-1 rounded-lg text-left px-1'>
                    <div class='d-inline-block'>
                        <input type='text' style="text-transform:capitalize;" 
                        id='custName' placeholder='Type your Name' ng-model="CustomerName" value='' 
                        typeahead='name for name in commonNames | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8' typeahead-show-hint="true" 
                        class="ttInput rounded-lg">
                    </div>
                    <button class='btn btn-xxs btn-danger alignright' ng-click='ClearCustName()'>CLEAR</button>
                </div>
                <button class='btn btn-primary btn-xxs mt-2' id='btnUpd' ng-click="UpdateCurOrder(1)"><i class="fas fa-save px-1"></i>Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you have missed to include required external javascript files reference in the application or html page and same I can see in the provided codepen link.
Include the required external javascript/css reference in head tag of your main page.
For your reference replace your head tag code with below head tag (which has external references) in the codepen and it should work

  <head>
    <style>
        .bgVideo { height: 100vh;}
    </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.2/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. For the convenience of reading your answer, I suggest you remove the description portion from the code mode. Thank you.